# Regex skips some matches by consuming from the input string

Tags: javascript, regex

I know why this problem occur but I need a way to solve it. Consider I have a string such:

```
var str = "123+53ff+124+ks23+223+22+mo";
```

and I want to replace the numbers between two `+` signs with `number` to get this:

```
str = "123+53ff+number+ks23+number+number+mo";
```

So I use this regular expression: `/\+\d+\+/g` like this:

```
str = str.replace(/\+\d+\+/g, "+number+");
```

But what it does is if there is more matches after each other (`+3+4+5+...`), it match one, skips the next, match the one after, skips the one after ...

I kind of know why this is happening: It's because when it matches one, then it consumes the right `+` and then start matching just after that `+` where the next element won't get matched because technically it's not surrounded by `+` signs.

If the input is `+3++4++5+` then the result is as expected because each number is surrounded by its own `+` signs (consuming one isn't a problem here beacause if one `+` is consumed the next one will do).

I've worked my way around this by calling the `replace` twice. But this is very hacky. I want a solid way. So, how to make the regular expression work here? Or how to make two consecutive numbers share the same `+` sign?

**Note:** I don't want to solve this particular example's issue (replace numbers between `+` signs). It was just an example of the issue.

**EDIT:**

If there is a way to do it, then can I group the `+` signs? I mean can I do this `/(\+).../` so I can access it using `$1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the **overlapping matches** aren't matched, you could use a positive lookahead in order to determine if there is a `+` character following the digit(s).

In doing so, you aren't actually matching the succeeding `+` since it is part of the lookahead:

[Example Here](https://regex101.com/r/xqu9Pz/1)

```
/\+\d+(?=\+)/g
```

For instance:

```
"123+53ff+124+ks23+223+22+mo".replace(/\+\d+(?=\+)/g, "+number");
```

Output:

```
"123+53ff+number+ks23+number+number+mo"
```

It's worth pointing out that you would use `+number` (rather than `+number+`) to replace the match now that the succeeding `+` is no longer being matched.

**Note:** If you want to group the `+` signs, group the first one like this: `/(\+)\d+(?=\+)/g` as the first one is sufficient. The second one will be automatically grouped in the next match.

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions only find non-overlapping matches. Once a match is found, the search is continued from match end. You can use lookaround assertions to add context without adding to the match itself:

```
/(?<=\+)\d+(?=\+)/
```

`(?<=\+)` asserts that before the current location there is a plus; `(?=\+)` asserts that after the current location there is a plus. Both of them are zero-width.

EDIT: JavaScript doesn't have lookbehind, so `/\+\d(?=\+)/` is what you can do in that case.

EDIT2: The lookaround assertions do not capture by themselves. You can't group the lookahead together with the match. However, you can group it independently, and concatenate later:

```
/(\+)(\d+)(?=(\+))/
```

will give you all three pieces.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have look-behinds. You will have to match the first `+`.

Comment: @4castle: Ah derp didn't see the tag.

Comment: What if I want to group the `+` signs. Does `(?=\+)` capture a group? I'll edit the question to include this issue too (if it's an issue of course).

Comment: @Amadan The second grouping is not valid. Since lookaheads aren't included in the match. Plus, just the first one will suffice since the next match will automatically include the next `+`. One note: add the global (`g`) modifier to the regular expression.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: Did you try it? `/(\+)(\d+)(?=(\+))/.exec("+12+")` gives `["+12", "+", "12", "+"]`, perfectly valid. As for "just the first one will suffice since the next match will automatically include the next `+`", it was directly in response to OP's "If there is a way to do it, then can I group the `+` signs?" (note the plural).

Comment: Yeah. But grouping the first one will suffice.